# 'std::vector<T>::iterator it;' doesn't compile

Tags: c++, stdvector

I've got this function:

```
    template<typename T>
    void Inventory::insertItem(std::vector<T>& v, const T& x)
    {
        std::vector<T>::iterator it; // doesn't compile
        for(it=v.begin(); it<v.end(); ++it)
        {
            if(x <= *it) // if the insertee is alphabetically less than this index
            {
                v.insert(it, x);
            }
        }
    }
```

and g++ gives these errors:

```
src/Item.hpp: In member function ‘void
yarl::item::Inventory::insertItem(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >&, const T&)’:  
src/Item.hpp:186: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’  
src/Item.hpp:187: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
```

it must be something simple, but after ten minutes of staring at it I can't find anything wrong.  Anyone else see it?

Comment: btw, you shouldn't use `it < v.end()` -- it will work with `vector` but not with `list`s and other containers. You should just always use `it != v.end()` to be sure.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator it;
```

Here's a page that describes [how to use typename](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) and why it's necessary here.

Comment: +1 for concise answer and a link for the detailed explanation.

Comment: TLDR: typename is mandatory before a qualified, dependent name which refers to a type. A qualified name is anything that is scoped to with the :: (example std::cout, OuterClass::InnerClass, etc.). A dependent name is anything that uses a generic template (e.g. GenericWrapperClass<T>, vector<T>, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

What you are doing is inefficient. Use a binary search instead:

```
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
void insertItem(std::vector<T>& v, const T& x)
{
    v.insert(std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), x), x);
}
```

Comment: +1 -- beat me to it. It's probably also worth mentioning that since the current code doesn't break out of the loop after doing the insertion, it'll typically insert extra copies of the new item where they're not desired.

Comment: @Jerry: Even worse, if the vector's size equals its capacity, `insert` will invalidate all iterators obtained prior to the insertion, so `++it` will lead straight into undefined behavior land.

Comment: +1 (but wish I could give +10). Looking at the code a second time, the build error is but one minor problem compared to the runtime behavior of the code.

Comment: Your answer helped me after 4 years. YOLO!