# Failing syntactically to write a C++ template function for getting sub-vector

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
template<typename T> void get_sub_vector(const std::vector<T>& vec, int begin_index, int end_index, std::vector<T>& dst) {
    std::vector<T>::const_iterator first = vec.begin() + begin_index;
    std::vector<T>::const_iterator last = vec.begin() + end_index - 1;
    dst = std::vector<T>(first, last);
}
```

The code purpose is to get:

- source std::vector of any type
- destination std::vector of the same type
- begin index and end index

Then it should copy all the values from the source vector, between the defined indices, into the destination vector.

I get the following compilation error:

```
error: need `typename` before `std::vector<T>::const_iterator` because `std::vector<T>` is a dependent scope
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with the templates syntax?

Comment: The duplicate question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144604/stdvectortiterator-it-doesnt-compile

Comment: The error message could NOT be more clear.